# "This is a beautiful pants" or "This are beautiful pants"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

How should I refer to things that are necessarily to be in pair but they are as one, such as pants, trousers, tweezers, scissors, glasses? Should I refer them as singular or as plural in the sentences as follow:

> "This **is** a beautiful pants"
>
> "This **are** beautiful pants"?
>
> This **is** the best tweezers that you can have.
>
> These **are** the best tweezers that you can have.
>
> It **is** a nice glasses.
>
> They **are** nice glasses.

Comment: All those items can also be  preceded by **a pair of** and that would make them singular.

Comment: This is a pair of paints/glasses/tweezers etc.

Comment: These are pants/glasses/tweezers etc.